# chicken and egg problem in aws cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to deploy my entire infrastructure via CloudFormation. The stack includes a Lambda function, which has to be added from an s3 bucket. The bucket is not created until the stack is created, but the stack need the bucket and the .zip inside the bucket to exist, in order to create the lambda.

I can create a manual s3 bucket, upload the zip file, and just not have it part of the stack. This approach would work, but I would like everything to be in the stack.

Comment: Typically you would use CDK, SAM or Serverless Framework rather than native CloudFormation when building infrastructure and building/deploying code to that infrastructure. Arguably, CDK has the most momentum here.

Comment: In my case, the lambda is not main code, but a custom authorizer for IoT Core

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the answer as I was writing it. `aws cloudformation package` command is specifically for this problem. It still requires an external bucket, but at least this seems to be the idiomatic approach.